# Dynamic slicing tensor to a list of ones with uneven shapes in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice, tensor

Given a 3D source tensor `t` (`batch_size`, `height`, `width`) and another 2D tensor `l` indicating the length. I want to do something like:

```
rslt = tf.dynamic_slice(t, l)
```

such that `rslt[0] = t[:l[0][0], :l[0][1]]`,  `rslt[1] = t[:l[1][0], :l[1][1]]` and so on. But as I know, `tf.slice` can not do this. Could you tell me how can I do the dynamic slicing in tensorflow? Thanks a lot!